# How to "ingest" a base64 encoded document/attachment using Elasticsearch Node.js Client

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, client

Elasticsearch Node.js Client: how to ingest a base64 encoded document.

I have successfully created an index ("descriptions") and a pipeline ("attachment") using Kibana to ingest base64 encoded documents.

Using the Elasticsearch Node.js Client, I then call client.index() to process a base64 encoded document, but I get "ResponseError: Exception" returned.

Code is included in this question.

```
// KIBANA
PUT /descriptions
PUT _ingest/pipeline/attachment
{
  "description" : "Extract attachment information",
  "processors" : [
    {
      "attachment" : {
        "field" : "data"
      }
    }
  ]
}

// NODE.JS code
// The 'data' variable is base64 encoded
function indexBase64Data(data) {

    console.log(" ");
    console.log("calling client.index()");
    const index = client.index({
        id: 101,
        index: "descriptions",
        pipeline: "attachment",
        body: {
            "data": data
        }
    });
    index.then(() => {
        console.log("Index was successful...");
    },
    (error) => {
        console.error("ERROR in client.index: " + error);
    })

}

// ERROR from client.index() is: "ResponseError: Exception"
```

I expected the base64 encoded document to be indexed by Elasticsearch, but I get this exception error: "ResponseError: Exception"

Perhaps client.index() is not the correct call. If so, I would like a suggestion on how to ingest attachments using the Elasticsearch Node.js Client.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is this that the base64 encoded data has a prefix that must be removed:

```
data:application/octet-stream;base64,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
```

Remove the prefix "data:application/octet-stream;base64,", and the code works.